# loading XML string into Xslt sheet

Tags: php, xslt, dom

I am trying to load a xml document I created using PHP and DOM into a xslt sheet, but having no luck.

```
$xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
//echo $xml_string;

$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load($xml_string);

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('musicInformation.xslt');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

I created a xml file based off some data extracted from a database and instead of saving it as an actual document I saved it as a string, I put the string into the xslt sheet and this error occurred

> Warning: I/O warning : failed to load
>   external entity Warning: xpath.c:11079
>   Internal error: document without root
>   in
>   /home/dd615/public_html/webservice.php
>   on line 73

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about posting the error message, or the actual problem you are having? Saying you are not having much luck doesn't tell anyone what the actual problem is.

Comment: sorry about that, uhh I created a file xml file based off some data extracted from a database and instead of saving it as an actual document I saved it as a string, I put the string into the xslt sheet and this error occured 

Warning: I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Warning: xpath.c:11079 Internal error: document without root in /home/dd615/public_html/webservice.php on line 73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is not XML.

Valid XML needs a [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) (that is, a single element that wraps all other elements in the document, apart from the XML declaration).

Such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <element></element>
  <element></element>
  ...
</root>
```

If you have multiple such roots, the XML is not valid and will fail to load.